# RemoteApp: Can one be sure that no unwanted programs are started?

Tags: windows, security, sql-server

Back story:
In our company, we bought a client/server process management software from which the client directly communicates with an SQL server. This is in my opinion a major security flaw, because it is possible to read the SQL server password from the registry on all client computers. This SQL user has access to the whole database. The software is user based, which is obviously only placebo and adds no security.
The manufacturer of the software is aware of the problem, but only offers a web access module to prevent the direct communication with the SQL server, which would cost additional ~5000$.

So I wondered if it is a good idea to set up another Windows Server where I install the client software and publish it as "RemoteApp".
I wondered if this would be sufficient to prevent users to start any non-published programs? I know that if the client software starts any additional software, the user would have access to this software too. This is only the case for PDF readers or other text editors.

Considering this information, can I assume that it is not possible to read out the registry keys and/or start any software (network sniffer or so on) that is uploaded by a RemoteApp user?

Comment: **This is highly insecure.** Users should only be allowed to access anything they should access and should always be logged and/or monitored. And database servers open to the internet are extremely dangerous.

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable The OP clearly understands that the app is insecure as supplied by the vendor, and he/she is asking us whether RemoteApp might be one way to reduce the risk that this application is bringing into his/her environment. The answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can manage this using Software Restriction Policies and/or AppLocker on the RemoteApp server. You definitely do not want the client running on end users' workstations due to the security concerns that you mentioned, unless those security concerns are written off by management following a thorough and well-documented discussion of the risks.

If you wish, it's possible to take additional steps to lock down the RemoteApp server. For example, I've changed RemoteApp users' default shell from `explorer.exe` to `logoff.exe` to prevent non-RemoteApp RDP logins.

You are correct in *not* expecting RemoteApp itself to provide a layer of  security. All it does is adjust the user's view of the application to make it look like it is running locally. You still need to manage the RemoteApp server's security configuration as though the RemoteApp users are logging in normally via RDP.